# Inline assembly not working when put inside main()

Tags: c, assembly, arm, inline-assembly, eabi

When I put the following inline assembly in `main()` it stops directly after `printf("before\n")`. Apparently there's something wrong with the inline assembly block since `printf("after\n")` is not printed. Same inline assembly runs perfectly when put in an own function `run()` and called within `main()` with `mainssv();`. What's wrong with this block?

```
int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        printf("before\n");

        asm volatile(
        ".syntax unified\n"
        ".text\n"
        ".arch armv7-a\n"
        ".fpu neon\n"
        ".thumb\n"
        ".global mainssv\n"
        ".func mainssv\n"
        ".thumb_func\n"
        "mainssv:\n"
        "        mov         lr, pc\n"
        "        adds        lr, lr, #63\n"
        "        bic         lr, lr, #63\n"
        "        mov         ip, 16\n"
        "    .p2align 2\n"
        "0:\n"
        "    .rept 130\n"
        "        vld2.8      {q0}, [lr, :128], ip\n"
        "        vaba.u8     q4, q4, q3\n"
        "        bne         1f\n"
        "1:      vld2.8      {q1}, [lr, :128], ip\n"
        "        vaba.u8     q5, q5, q0\n"
        "        vld2.8      {q2}, [lr, :128], ip\n"
        "        vaba.u8     q6, q6, q1\n"
        "        bne         1f\n"
        "1:      vld2.8      {q3}, [lr, :128], ip\n"
        "        vaba.u8     q7, q7, q2\n"
        "        smuad       r0, r1, r2\n"
        "        subs        lr, lr, #64\n"
        "    .endr\n"
        "        bne         0b\n"
        ".endfunc"
        );

        printf("after\n");
        }
}
```

Comment: You can't insert a function into another function like this. Your asm statement expects to be called by another function.

Comment: My guess without knowing too much ARM assembly: The code for `mainssv` is just dumped inside main and executed as part of main (without a function call). Returning from `mainssv` would return early from main instead, which explains the symptoms. But as noted by @RossRidge **this should not be supported at all**.

Comment: After further reading: Since `mainssv()` is not called, but just executed in the flow of `main()`, `.func mainssv` saves the return address for `main()` onto the stack, which is what gets pushed into the instruction pointer by `.endfunc`. Hence `encfunc` returns from `main()` and the `printf("after\n")` is thus never reached.

Comment: @dhke Except `.endfunc` is just a directive related to debugging information, it isn't a return (it wouldn't even know what kind of return instruction to emit!). Regardless, looking at the mess that is the disassembly after compiling this, there are so many things wrong that it's not even worth trying to reason about.

Comment: @Notlikethat Good to know, the docs I was able to dig up, where quite vague and seemed to indicate that `.endfunc` was allowed to emit a *pull value from stack and push it into ip*. I stand corrected, then. Also: We don't even know what compiler was used.

Comment: Single-step through your code with a debugger, and see what it does.  That's how you debug asm.  Running it and just looking at what it prints gives you so much less information.